# How to generalize similar namespaces of mappers in MyBatis?

Tags: java, mybatis, mybatis-mapper

There is an XML mapping associated with an interface `FirstMapper`:

```
<mapper namespace="my.very.long.path.to.package.with.mappers.FirstMapper">
  <select id="selectAll" resultType="map">
    SELECT * FROM my_table
  </select> 
</mapper>
```

The `namespace` contains full name including the package name, which has the same long prefix for all mappers. **Is there a possibility to generalize (or parameterize) this prefix?**

For example, instead of mappers with these declarations

```
1. <mapper namespace="my.very.long.path.to.package.with.mappers.FirstMapper"> ...
2. <mapper namespace="my.very.long.path.to.package.with.mappers.abc.SecondMapper"> ...
3. <mapper namespace="my.very.long.path.to.package.with.mappers.xyz.ThirdMapper"> ...
```

it would be good to have something similar to

```
1. <mapper namespace="FirstMapper"> ...
2. <mapper namespace="abc.SecondMapper"> ...
3. <mapper namespace="xyz.ThirdMapper"> ...
```

or at least

```
1. <mapper namespace="${nsPrefix}.FirstMapper"> ...
2. <mapper namespace="${nsPrefix}.abc.SecondMapper"> ...
3. <mapper namespace="${nsPrefix}.xyz.ThirdMapper"> ...
```

Comment: Oh, sorry man. Apparently I can't read.  For that I have no idea.

Comment: @diziaq You can assign any namespace, but then MyBatis won't be able to bind your XML mapper to the corresponding Java mapper. See the 'note about namespace' section in the [startup guide](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html#).

Comment: @ave I do have short namespaces that are unrelated to the Java classes (I use SpringBoot with `@MapperScan` annotation). Why do you say MyBatis won't find them?

Comment: @TheImpaler There should be no problem if the XML mapper has no related Java mapper.  The binding I mentioned was about the case when there is a pair of Java and XML mapper.